# Meaning of square brackets "[]" when querying RDF with SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, rdf, turtle-rdf

I am pretty new to SPARQL and RDF and I was wondering what exactly does the below mean in SPARQL?

```
[] vc:n ?vcard .
```

The complete query is

```
PREFIX vc: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#>

SELECT ?given ?family

WHERE{

    [] vc:n ?vcard .

    OPTIONAL {?vcard vc:given-name ?given .}

    OPTIONAL {?vcard vc:family-name ?family .}

}
```

Comment: The answer here may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311732/what-are-brackets-in-sparql-and-why-is-the-linked-movie-database-limited-to-2500

Comment: @MarcBaumbach It's more than useful,  it's a duplicate. [What are brackets in SPARQL and why is the linked movie database limited to 2500 records?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22311732/1281433).  "Brackets" in the title of that question refers to square brackets, i.e., `[` and `]`.

Comment: I've also added the [tag:turtle] tag, since this syntax is shared (for the most part, if not exactly) with the Turtle serialization of RDF.

Comment: Thank You all. This was pretty helpful. I would be even more grateful if any of you could give me a brief idea as to what exactly does that line do that is "[] vc:n ?vcard ." As far as I understand it is of the triple format. What does vc:n do?

Answer (score 8):

> *This is cannibalized from my answer to [What are brackets in SPARQL and why is the linked movie database limited to 2500 records?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22311732/1281433), of which this question*
>   may *be a duplicate, although it's a bit more broad.  (It asks two
>   questions, whereas this asks just one.)  The answer is mostly links and citations of the SPARQL specification.*

### [ … ] is a blank node

The square brackets are described in the [SPARQL 1.1 Query Language](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/).  In particular, see [4.1.4 Syntax for Blank Nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#QSynBlankNodes)

> #### [4.1.4 Syntax for Blank Nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#QSynBlankNodes)
>
> Blank nodes in graph patterns act as variables, not as references to
>   specific blank nodes in the data being queried.
>
> Blank nodes are indicated by either the label form, such as `"\_:abc"`,
>   or the abbreviated form `"[]"`. A blank node that is used in only one
>   place in the query syntax can be indicated with `[]`. A unique blank
>   node will be used to form the triple pattern. Blank node labels are
>   written as `"_:abc"` for a blank node with label "abc". The same blank
>   node label cannot be used in two different basic graph patterns in the
>   same query.
>
> The `[:p :v]` construct can be used in triple patterns. It creates a
>   blank node label which is used as the subject of all contained
>   predicate-object pairs. The created blank node can also be used in
>   further triple patterns in the subject and object positions.
>
> The following two forms
>
> ```
> [ :p "v" ] .
> [] :p "v" .
> ```
>
> allocate a unique blank node label (here "b57") and are equivalent to
>   writing:
>
> ```
> _:b57 :p "v" .
> ```
>
> This allocated blank node label can be used as the subject or object
>   of further triple patterns. For example, as a subject:
>
> ```
> [ :p "v" ] :q "w" .
> ```
>
> which is equivalent to the two triples:
>
> ```
> _:b57 :p "v" .
> _:b57 :q "w" .
> ```
>
> and as an object:
>
> ```
> :x :q [ :p "v" ] .
> ```
>
> which is equivalent to the two triples:
>
> ```
> :x  :q _:b57 .
> _:b57 :p "v" .
> ```

Answer (score 7):

`[]` is a blank node in a query.  It acts like a named variable except you can't use it in a `SELECT` project or `FILTER` or anywhere where you need to name the variable.  You can replace `[]` with a named variable using a name not used anywhere in the query.  `SELECT *` would add it but otherwise it is much the same query.

Comment: I think this answer is relatively easier to catch for someone who is pretty new to SPARQL.